# Traefik Reverse Proxy Redirect HTTP request to same port as HTTPS request

Tags: docker, reverse-proxy, traefik

[www.example.com](http://www.example.com) points to the public IP of my backend server. I have set up NAT forwarding rules on the backend server pointing to different services, as such I would like to use https://www.example.com:/health to be accepted and then redirected to port /health

I've tried to use a middleware but have been unsuccessful so far.

.env:

```
REGEX_PATTERN=^(https://[^/]+):([^/]+)/?(.*)$
REGEX_REPLACEMENT=$${1}/$${3}:\$${2}`
```

docker-compose.yml:

```
services:
  whoami:
    image: "traefik/whoami"
    container_name: "simple-service"
    labels:
      - "traefik.enable=true"
      - "traefik.http.routers.whoami-rule1.rule=Host(`www.example.com`)"
      - "traefik.http.routers.whoami-rule1.entrypoints=websecure"
      - "traefik.http.routers.whoami-rule1.tls.certresolver=myresolver"
      - "traefik.http.routers.whoami-rule1.middlewares=whoami-rule1-port-redirect"
      - "traefik.http.middlewares.whoami-rule1-port-redirect.redirectregex.regex=${REGEX_PATTERN}"
      - "traefik.http.middlewares.whoami-rule1-port-redirect.redirectregex.replacement=${REGEX_REPLACEMENT}"
      - "traefik.http.middlewares.whoami-rule1-port-redirect.redirectregex.permanent=true"
```

The containers build successfully, but the SSL check is not working.

I can curl successfully http://www.example.com:7001/health, but https://www.example.com:7001/health does not work. The idea is that the port 7001 can vary for different containers, and I would like to create one container which does the simple redirecting instead of making a container for each port since there are alot of services (and ports)

I tried to create a separate container for each port, but that creates too many containers to manage and defeats the point for having a one-stop check for SSL issues in the future.

Answer (score 0):

It would be good if you also shared the rest of your traefik configuration (where you set up the `entrypoints`). Are you actually running a `traefik` container?

In general, traefik will listen to the ports which are assigned to entrypoints. Usually this means one for `http`(80) and one for `https`("websecure", 443).
The "beauty" of using a reverse proxy is that you can use **one** port that accepts all the traffic which is then forwarded to the appropriate container based on rules that are set up (for example by matching the host address).

I don't see where port `7001` comes from. Is this the port assigned to your `websecure` entrypoint? AFAIK, the `whoami` container listens on port `80`.

I also think that it is not possible to change the port via a redirectregex (and again, this should not be necessary since we are using a reverse proxy).